# How to use AutoPlay methods with React-slick useRef hook and typescript

Tags: reactjs, typescript, react-hooks, ref, react-slick

I'm currently using `"typescript": "^3.7.5"` and `"react-slick": "^0.25.2"`.

The problem I am facing is that I'm not able to use the auto play methods `slickPlay` and `slickPause` with the new `useRef` hook and typescript.

Goal: To be able to pause auto play and resume auto play with a play/pause button. My play/pause button will be next to the pagination dots.

My Code:

```
import React, { useStateuseRef } from 'react';

const myComponent = () => {
  const [autoPlayOn, setAutoPlayOn] = useState<boolean>(true);
  const sliderRef = useRef<typeof Slider | null>(null);
  
  <Slider
    ref={sliderRef}
    appendDots={(dots): JSX.Element => (
      <MyButton
        onClick={() => {
          setAutoPlayOn(!autoPlayOn);
          if (autoPlayOn) {
            sliderRef.slickPlay();
          } else {
            sliderRef.slickPause();
          }
        }}
      />
    )}
    {...otherSettings}
  >
}
```

The type error that I am getting is:

```
No overload matches this call.
  Overload 1 of 2, '(props: Readonly<Settings>): Slider', gave the following error.
    Type 'MutableRefObject<typeof Slider | null>' is not assignable to type 'string | ((instance: Slider | null) => void) | RefObject<Slider> | null | undefined'.
      Type 'MutableRefObject<typeof Slider | null>' is not assignable to type 'RefObject<Slider>'.
        Types of property 'current' are incompatible.
          Type 'typeof Slider | null' is not assignable to type 'Slider | null'.
            Type 'typeof Slider' is missing the following properties from type 'Slider': slickNext, slickPause, slickPlay, slickPrev, and 8 more.
  Overload 2 of 2, '(props: Settings, context?: any): Slider', gave the following error.
    Type 'MutableRefObject<typeof Slider | null>' is not assignable to type 'string | ((instance: Slider | null) => void) | RefObject<Slider> | null | undefined'.
      Type 'MutableRefObject<typeof Slider | null>' is not assignable to type 'RefObject<Slider>'.
```

I'm also getting another error when clicking on the button:
`TypeError: sliderRef.slickPlay is not a function`

I'm attempting to call the slick methods `slickPlay` and `slickPause`, however I'm running into type errors. I've looked at the examples https://github.com/akiran/react-slick/blob/master/examples/AutoPlayMethods.js however I'm not able to achieve the desired result still.

It confuses me to use these methods for functional components instead of class-based components.  Adding in the layer of typescript makes it that much more challenging.

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I'll address the second part first: when using `useRef`, you have to refer to `.current` to get the actual instance. So, your calls would look like:

```
sliderRef.current.slickPlay();
```

Now the first part. This one, I'm willing to believe that this could change depending on which version of Typescript/React/react-slick you're using, but for me, Typescript stops complaining if I just use:

```
const sliderRef = React.useRef<Slider>(null);
```

Comment: I'm still getting an error `Object is possibly 'null'` for `sliderRef`

Comment: How about `sliderRef.current?.slickPlay()`  ?

Comment: I was able to get it to work by checking `sliderRef.current` instead of making the check on `sliderRef`

Answer (score 0):

I was able to get this to work by making a check on `.current` instead of `sliderRef`.

```
const sliderElement = sliderRef.current;

if (sliderElement) {
  // do stuff
}
```

This small nuance was able to pass the type errors.

For the `useRef` declaration, this line worked(thanks to help from @jnpdx)

```
const sliderRef = React.useRef<Slider | null>(null);
```